# GKE conflict after automatic upgrade of master node kubernetes version

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Today our cluster went down and gcloud console output looked like this:

```
]$ gcloud container clusters list
NAME                 ZONE            MASTER_VERSION  MASTER_IP   MACHINE_TYPE   NODE_VERSION  NUM_NODES  STATUS
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  europe-west1-d  1.6.11-gke.0    xx.xx.xx.x  n1-standard-1  1.6.4 *       2          ERROR
```

As one can see, the kubernetes master version differs from the version of the node pool. This introduced a conflict within the cluster. The conflict could be solved after upgrading the node pool to the proper version.

What I am trying to understand now is: Why was the master on a different version in the first place. Is there an automatic update policy, that we should have known about? But if the answer is "yes": why was the node pool not upgraded accordingly?

Comment: In a K8s Cluster, there are are a lot of componetns, for instance, kubelet ,kube-proxy etc   I would like to know more about which components were having the different version in the cluster?  
As far as I know, consistency (same version) of kubelet and kube-proxy is necessary for avoiding the delays, erros in the cluster.

Comment: Can you explain "This introduced a conflict within the cluster"? Are you getting an error (if so, please add it to your question). It’s normal that the MASTER_VERSION can be greater than NODE_VERSION. In GKE, nodes and master are upgraded separately.

Comment: Except from the "ERROR"-Status already listed, there was no specific error message. Fixing this was mostly guess work since we coul not connect via kubectl either (iirc), first we thought the nodes are just dead somehow, and added more, before finally upgrading the node pool version.
Regarding the independant upgrade of master/pool: thats good to know, we never really thought about that. But if this automatic upgrade process can kill the clluster, we would really like to know beforehand when those upgrades are scheduled.